# Change speed of Sequential Transition via a Slider Java FX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Sequential Transition and I have a slider. The slider will be used to change the speed of the Sequential Transition (as the animation is playing). However, I am not too sure how to do this. I tried to use the slider to change the duration of the animation but it did not seem to work the duration just stayed at 0 and so the animation would not even play.

It would be great if someone could maybe show a small simplified example of my problem.

Thank you.

EDIT:

So binding the slider value to the rate property allows me to change the speed of animations efficiently. However I want my Slider value to start in the middle I tried:

```
animationSpeedSlider = new Slider(1, 4, 2);
```

But that did not work. I also tried to set the value manually like:
    animationSpeedSlider = new Slider(1, 4, 2);
    animationSpeedSlider.setValue(2);

That did not seem to work either, in both cases the slider value is still to the far left.

Also, I want the speed not to be 0 when it is at the far left which is why I put the lower bound to 1 but it seems to still stop the animation.

Comment: Use the `Slider` to change the value of the [`rate`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#rateProperty) property.

Comment: it's your job to provide a [mcve] of what you tried and what exactly you want to achieve :) btw: reading the api doc helps more often than not ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way of adjusting the animation speed without stopping the animation is via the  `rate` property: The cycle duration of the animation is devided by the value of the `rate` property to determine the effective cycle duration.

**Example**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Duration d = Duration.seconds(1);

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50);
    TranslateTransition t1 = new TranslateTransition(d, rect);
    t1.setToX(350);
    TranslateTransition t2 = new TranslateTransition(d, rect);
    t2.setToY(350);
    TranslateTransition t3 = new TranslateTransition(d, rect);
    t3.setToX(0);
    TranslateTransition t4 = new TranslateTransition(d, rect);
    t4.setToY(0);

    SequentialTransition transition = new SequentialTransition(t1, t2, t3, t4);
    transition.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    transition.play();

    Pane pane = new Pane(rect);
    pane.setPrefSize(400, 400);

    Slider slider = new Slider(0.1, 4, 1);
    transition.rateProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty());

    stage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(slider, pane)));
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Hi Fabian so binding the rate property to the slider value worked, however I have a few other problems which can be seen in the edit, any chance you can help with those too?

Comment: @Jaman I cannot reproduce the issue described in your edit. (simply replaced the parameters for the slider constructor to `1, 4, 2` for testing in my example)